# How to use keys and values in a defined dictionary to describe values in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
car_categories = {0: "SUV", 1: "Convertible", 2: "Sports Car"}
```

and a list that looks like this:

```
cars = [0,1,1,1,2,0]
```

How can I use my dictionary to get an output that looks something like this (i.e. where the values in car are described using the keys in my dictionary)

```
0 corresponds to SUV
1 corresponds to Convertible
1 corresponds to Convertible
```

and so on for the remaining items in the list

Comment: You could simply loop the `cars`

Comment: I'm not sure what that would look like.

Comment: `for c in cars: print(c, cars_cat[c])`

Comment: Sorry my answer was not finished since I use phone

I think something like this:

```
`for c in cars:
    print(f"{c} corresponds to {car_categories[c]}")
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the value from the dictionary using the numbers in the list since they correspond to the keys:

```py
for car in cars:
    car_type = car_categories[car]
    print(f'{car} corresponds to {car_type}')
```

In response to the comment in case you are unsure if the key exists in the dictionary and you don't want to handle the exception, you could perform a safe get instead with a default message:

```py
for car in cars:
    car_type = car_categories.get(car, 'no known type')
    print(f'{car} corresponds to {car_type}')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood what you mean, by running this:

```
car_categories = {0: "SUV", 1: "Convertible", 2: "Sports Car"}
cars = [0,1,1,1,2,0]
for i in cars:
  print(i, "corresponds to", car_categories.get(i))
```

the output is:

```
0 corresponds to SUV
1 corresponds to Convertible
1 corresponds to Convertible
1 corresponds to Convertible
2 corresponds to Sports Car
0 corresponds to SUV
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a basic for loop. In each iteration, if `car` is the current element, the category of that element would be obtained by referencing `car_categories[car]` :

```py
for car in cars:
    print('%d corresponds to %s' % (car, car_categories[car]))
```